# "certain" in "This guy has certain reputation in this community"

Tags: grammar

Is the word ***certain*** appropriate in this sentence?

> This guy has **certain** reputation in this community?

Is that alright? Or is there a better way to put it?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners (ELL). Please edit your question and tell us what difficulties you are having. Otherwise, [proofreading is off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and your question risks being closed.

Comment: Although I think this question would be improved if the author added more details, I don't think it fits the "proofreading" close reason.  A specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Comment: See meaning #2 in the [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/certain)

Answer (score 2):

> This guy has **a** certain reputation in this community.

Reputation is a noun, so an article is needed. Otherwise it is OK, and the use of *certain* is correct.

You would say "This guy has **a** (certain) reputation in this community." because it is indefinite what kind of reputation it is. You can't use *the* for this reason.
However, you could say "This guy has **the** best reputation in this community." as this defines the kind of reputation he has.

Comment: The reason you need an **a** there isn't because of the noun (nouns don't always need articles in front of them in English).  Rather, *a certain X* is a set phrase.  You can't say "This guy has the certain reptutation."

Comment: @AaronBrown You would say "This guy has *a* (certain) reputation in this community." because it is indefinite what kind of reputation it is. You can't use "the" for this reason. You could say "This guy has *the best* reputation in this community." as this defines the kind of reputation he has.

Comment: You are exactly right. Your comment is a good explanation of why an 'a' is required there, you might even consider adding that to your answer.  I'm just pointing out that nouns do not require preceding articles in all cases.  See http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/english-as-a-second-language/articles